# Concurrency with multiple producers/multiple consumers

Tags: concurrency, go, producer-consumer

I'm probably missing something, or not understanding something in how Go handles concurrency (or in my knowledge of concurrency itself), i've devised a little bit of code to understand a multiple producer/consumer.

This is the code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
    // "math/rand"
    "sync"
)

var seq uint64 = 0
var generatorChan chan uint64
var requestChan chan uint64

func makeTimestamp() int64 {
    return time.Now().UnixNano() / int64(time.Millisecond)
}

func generateStuff(genId int) {
    var crap uint64
    for {
        crap = <-requestChan
        // <- requestChan
        seq = seq+1
        fmt.Println("Gen ", genId, " - From : ", crap, " @", makeTimestamp())
        generatorChan <- uint64(seq)
    }
}

func concurrentPrint(id int, work *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer work.Done()

    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        requestChan<-uint64(id)
        fmt.Println("Conc", id, ": ", <-generatorChan)
    }
}

func main() {
    generatorChan = make(chan uint64)
    requestChan = make(chan uint64)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for i := 0; i < 20; i++ {
        go generateStuff(i)
    }
    maximumWorker := 200
    wg.Add(maximumWorker)
    for i := 0; i < maximumWorker; i++ {
        go concurrentPrint(i, &wg)
    }
    wg.Wait()
}
```

When run it prints (mostly in order) all the numbers from 1 to 1000 (200 consumers getting a number 5 times each).
I would've expected that some consumer would print the exact same number but it seems that the *requestChan* is working like a barrier preventing this even if there are 20 goroutines serving the *generateStuff* that generate the number by increasing a global variable.

What am i getting wrong about Go or Concurrency in general?

I would've expected a situation in like two go routines of type *generateStuff* would've been woke up together and increase seq at the same time thus having something like two consumers printing the same number two times.

**EDIT** Code on playgolang: http://play.golang.org/p/eRzNXjdxtZ

Comment: Note, you have a potential data race with access to the global `seq` variable (except that the unbuffered `requestChan` may keep them apart).

Comment: Yeah that is what i would expect Dave, some non deterministic behaviour giving me not all the numbers from 1 to 1000 but something different.

In this example chans are buffered http://play.golang.org/p/tq7-6Bc0hL, still getting same results.

Comment: Have you run with `GOMAXPROCS` >1? (and perhaps with `-race`)

Comment: @DaveC Added `runtime.GOMAXPROCS(2)` in code and ran as `go run -race helloworld.go` i always get _1000_ as last `seq` print but the _go_ executable informs me of **Found 1 data race(s)**

Comment: @DaveC With 4 processor finally managed to get what i was expecting multiple goroutine printig the same number even with unbuffered chan. I would like to prize you with the right answer. thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have multiple workers that can all run at the same time and all try and make requests at the same time. Since `requestChan` is unbuffered they all block waiting for a reader to synchronize with and take their request.

You have multiple generators that will synchronize with a requester via `requestChan`, produce a result, and then block on the unbuffered `generatorChan` until a worker reads the result. Note it may be a different worker.

There is no additional synchronization so everything else is non-deterministic.

- One generator could field all the requests.
- A generator could grab a request and get through incrementing `seq`
  before any other generator happens to get a chance to run. With only one processor this may even be likely.
- All the generators could grab requests and all end up wanting to increment `seq` at exactly the same time causing all kinds of problems.
- The workers can get responses from the same generator they happened to send to or from a completely different one.

In general, without adding synchronization to force one of these behaviors there is no way you can ensure any of these actually happen.

Note that with the data race, that itself is another non-deterministic event. It's possible to get arbitrary values, program crashes, etc. It's not safe to assume that under race conditions the value may just be off by one or some such relatively innocuous result.

For experimenting, the best you may be able to do is crank up `GOMAXPROCS`. Either through an environment variable (e.g. something like `env GOMAXPROCS=16 go run foo.go` or `env GOMAXPROCS=16 ./foo` after `go build`) or by calling `runtime.GOMAXPROCS(16)` from your program. The default is 1 and this means that data races or other "strange" behavior may be hidden.

You can also influence things a little by adding calls to `runtime.Gosched` or `time.Sleep` at various points.

You can also see the data race if you use the race detector (e.g. with `go run -race foo.goo` or `go build -race`). Not only should the program show "Found 1 data race(s)" on exit but it should also dump out a lot of details with stack traces when the race is first detected.

Here is a "cleaned up" version of your code for experimentation:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "sync"
    "sync/atomic"
)

var seq uint64 = 0
var generatorChan = make(chan uint64)
var requestChan = make(chan uint64)

func generator(genID int) {
    for reqID := range requestChan {
        // If you want to see a data race:
        //seq = seq + 1
        // Else:
        s := atomic.AddUint64(&seq, 1)
        log.Printf("Gen: %2d, from %3d", genID, reqID)
        generatorChan <- s
    }
}

func worker(id int, work *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer work.Done()

    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        requestChan <- uint64(id)
        log.Printf("\t\t\tWorker: %3d got %4d", id, <-generatorChan)
    }
}

func main() {
    log.SetFlags(log.Lmicroseconds)
    const (
        numGen    = 20
        numWorker = 200
    )
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for i := 0; i < numGen; i++ {
        go generator(i)
    }
    wg.Add(numWorker)
    for i := 0; i < numWorker; i++ {
        go worker(i, &wg)
    }
    wg.Wait()
    close(requestChan)
}
```

[<kbd>Playground</kbd>](https://play.golang.org/p/UxOADthEbE) (but note that the timestamps on the playground won't be useful and calling `runtime.MAXPROCS` may not do anything). Further note that the playground caches results so re-running the exact same program will always show the same output, you need to make some small change or just run it on your own machine.

Largely small changes like shunting down the generator, using `log` versus `fmt` since the former makes concurrency guarantees, removing the data race, making the output look nicer, etc.